# Existence of $\{a_n\}$ s.t $f(\vec{v})=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n v_n$ for continuous linear functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

**disclaimer:** this is a homework assignment, I'm looking for a hint or a word of advice, not a full solution.

Let $f: l^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, linear function. Prove that there exists a bounded sequence $\{a_n\}$ of real numbers such that $$f(\textbf{v})=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n v_n$$ for $\textbf{v} \in l^1$, and where $\textbf{v}=(v_1,v_2,...)$.

Okay, so the first thing I noticed was that the question is icognito hiding the fact that we can define a vector $\textbf{a}=(a_1,...)$ so that $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n v_n=\langle\textbf{a},\textbf{v}\rangle$$

So in truth, we are trying to show that for all continuous linear functions $f: l^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ there exists a vector in $\textbf{a} \in l^1$ so that $f(\textbf{v})=\langle\textbf{a}, \textbf{v} \rangle$ for all $\textbf{v} \in l^1$.

Okay, so first of all, I need to show taht $f$ is bounded:

**lemma:** we show that if $f$ is a continuous linear function $l^1 \to \mathbb{R}$, it is bounded.

Let $\epsilon=1$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ so that $||\textbf{v}||_1< \delta \implies ||f(\textbf{v})||_2 \leq 1$.

Assume $\textbf{v}$ is non trivial. but then $$||\frac{\delta \textbf{v}}{||\vec{v}||_1}||_1=\delta$$ so by linearity we obtain that

$$||\frac{\delta f(\textbf{v})}{||\textbf{v}||}||_2 \leq 1 \implies ||f(\textbf{v})||_2 \leq \frac{1}{\delta} ||\vec{v}||.$$

q.e.d

Okay, so from here, I'm having trouble explicitly expressing the desired vector $\textbf{a}$. I know that if $f$ is a trivial linear function, then we are done, since we just choose the zero vector. Any hints would be appreciated.

*Side note:* do these results generalize? I haven't used anything about $l^1$ or $\mathbb{R}$ in particular so far (or have I w.o realizing it?)

Comment: $\bf a$ doesn't need to be in $\ell^1$. It has to be in $\ell^\infty$. In other words $\ell^\infty$ is the dual space of $\ell^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not any different from the finite-dimensional case.

Let $\mathbf{e}_n$ be the sequence whose components are all zeros except the $n$th component being $1$. Then $\mathbf{v} = \sum_n v_n \mathbf{e}_n$. Can you use this to write $f(\mathbf{v})$ in a different form? Does this suggest what the $a_n$ are? Once you have this, proving the rest (e.g., boundedness) should not be difficult.

Comment: I was very much overthinking the problem. I did look it up, and it seems like the results are extendable to hilbert spaces in general